# Node.js Forver keeps stopping other services running on the same box

Tags: javascript, node.js, forever

I am using Node.js forever to run a web service and a website on my machine.

These services are in files called app.js and site.js respectively

I run multiple environments on the same box and have been having a devil of a time keeping the production or development instances up as every time I start both services one seems to kill the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that node js uses the name of the script as an index rather than its full path.

Thus if the following commands are run

```
user@somehost:somepath/dev/someservice/$ forever app.js start
user@somehost:somepath/dev/someservice/$ cd ../../prod/someservice
user@somehost:somepath/prod/someservice/$ forever app.js start
```

With hindsight it was kind of obvious that the issue was with the stopping of the serivces. Now when running

```
user@somehost:somepath/prod/someservice/$ forever app.js stop
```

Both the services stop. This problem is easily addressed by using the Fully Qualified Path to the JavaScript file.